# Mule Date Conversion

Tags: mule, datamapper

My scenario

My Mule flow reads a file and update Salesforce.

Date field in file - 6/2/2015  5:06:00 AM

It will be updated in a datetime field in Salesforce. I am not able to figure out the mapping in the data mapper. Any pointers please.. Thanks!

Comment: Have you given  any mappings  in DataMapper for Date field?.Have you check what was the payload coming out from DM?. Could you please elaborate your question.

Comment: @star Yes it is in the data mapper where the parsing gives me exception.  Script in my data mapper looks like output.time__c = input.timefieldincsv

Comment: @star i have used str2calendar and everything is working fine now.  But timezone is not matching . How to set timezone in str2calendar

Answer (score 0):

1.Right click the field ( Date field) in Data Mapper- In format Option, place your required format  example:`dd.MM.yyyy`. if it is not working, try the below option

2. Can also use the script to format Date

   output.Required_Date = calendar2str(input.validDate, "dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss");

Please read DataMapper documents for more details